# Why Laravel 5 hashes password twice?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I set hash mutator for User model:

```php
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    \Log::info('Hash');
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($value);
}
```

Then I have a register function. The password hashes twice (checked in logs)

```php
public function register(RegisterNewUser $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->admin = true;
    $user->save();

    $this->auth->login($user);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

Actually the function was originally written like this:

```php
$user = new User($request->all());
$user->admin = true;
$user->save();
```

With the same result. Password gets hashed twice and I can't figure why.

I even tried:

```
get('test', function() {
    $user = \CRM\EloquentModels\User::create([
        'email' => 'zzz@zzz.zzz',
        'last_name' => 'zzz',
        'password' => 123
    ]);
});
```

And it gets hashed twice. No idea...

Comment: It looks correct at first glance. Have you tried using the traditional `User::create($arrayOfValues)` approach?

Comment: Yeah, I tried... look the update.

Comment: I tested the same approach with creating a `new User()` and setting its password value, logging the mutator, and I only get one log as expected. Try clearing the logs and running a single request to ensure that it is running twice.

Comment: I tried a lot of times, because actually after registering a user I can't log in because of that. I puth \Hash::log('Hashed') into the mutator and I always see two lines in logs. I guess something wrong with my whole application, but I can't figure out where it might happen. Even in test route (not in a controller or somewhere) I got the mistake :(

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Laravel? Can you try running `composer update`?

Comment: I did. Carbon was updated but still the same behavior. Laravel 5.0.13. Guess need to get stacktrace or something like that to understand what makes it hash twice

Comment: You don't have any save events set up for the user model do you?

Comment: Exactly... how silly I am. Actually I extend BaseModel, where I rewrite all fields. If a field is empty (empty string) I set it to null, otherwise I set it like it was, $model->{$key} = empty($value) ? null : $value; So I set password twice.

Comment: woah thank you! I had the exactly same issue. In my case, my Base model implements Transformable from Laravel 5 Repositories. Thus, the mutator has being called twice